# Dynamic X-axis limits in Excel graph generated by xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, graph, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to reference specific cells to set min & max axis.
The aim is to have two cells in the excel file generated which set minimum and maximum value for X axis in order to be able to scale it in a fast way.

I already tried

```
chart.set_x_axis({ 'min':['Dati',     0,1], 'max':['Dati',     1,1], })
```

I also tried to refer to a specific cell with 'C7', but the output file appears to be corrupted.

Comment: You cant set the axis range from values you set to cell(s) while creating the worksheet. The cells don't have values until everything is created at the end, but either way it wouldn't be dynamic. I **think** the only option would be to create a macro that updates the `'Axis Options'` Bounds in the sheet when a cell min and/or max is changed.

Comment: I agree with @moken. This isn't something that can be done in Excel (outside of a macro) so, as such, it can't be done with XlsxWriter.